# Using XPath to search XML

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XML stored on a URL. I'm parsing that URL from my Android app. Let the URL be

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/books.xml

I want to use XPath to traverse through some nodes and display results. But when I went through the tutorials, I came to know that the XML file must be stored within the project. I mean something like this:

```
Document document = builder.parse(new File("/books.xml"));
```

Can XPath work if I give the URL of the XML file i.e http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/books.xml rather than saving the file first and then using it?

**EDIT**: Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
// data
ArrayList<String> mPeople = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        parseData();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // pass adapter w/ data queried through XPath to ListView
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mPeople);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private void parseData() throws Exception {
    // create an InputSource object from /res/raw

     DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = db.parse(new URL("http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/books.xml").openConnection().getInputStream());
       doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    // query XPath instance, this is the parser
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    // specify the xpath expression
    String expression = " /bookstore/book/title ";
    // list of nodes queried
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    Toast.makeText(this, "count: " + String.valueOf(nodes.getLength()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // if node found
    if(nodes != null && nodes.getLength() > 0) {
        mPeople.clear();
        int len = nodes.getLength();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            // query value
            Node node = nodes.item(i);
            mPeople.add(node.getTextContent());
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use `new URL(yourURL).openConnection().openStream()` and pass that stream to the builder parse method.

Comment: You mean this? `Document document = builder.parse(new URL("myURL").openConnection.openStream());`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it says: `The method openStream() is undefined for the type URLConnection`

Comment: Yeah, my fault, it's `getInputStream()`, not `openStream()`.

Comment: Nothing happened! The log cat says: `error opening trace file. No such file or directory (2)`

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code you've written and the error stack trace?

Comment: That error comes from something else, I just ran your code in a basic `main` method and it works as expected. (I removed the `Toast` and anything related to `mPeople`.) You must be getting the error from some other service.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've cleaned the project too but still no use. It is catching Exception..